# How can I make a WordPress plugin appear on the left side of the admin dashboard?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, dashboard

enter image description here
[How to make a WordPress plugin appear on the left side of the admin dashboard?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nycxu.png)

Answer (score 0):

first create a folder in plugins with your plugin name
plugins/my-plugin

create a php file my-plugin.php in same folder
and add this code

```
<?php

/*
* Plugin Name: My Custom Plugin
* Plugin URI: https://stackoverflow.com
* Author: Carlos Gutierrez
* Author URI: https://stackoverflow.com
* Version: 1.0.0
* Description: Plugin description
* License:GPLv2 or later
*/


add_action('admin_menu' , 'mrn_add_menu');
function mrn_add_menu(){

add_menu_page('page title'  , 'menu title'  , 'administrator' , 'plugin_slug' , 'show_page_menu' , 'icon_path' , 17.23);


}

function show_page_menu(){
    echo "hello wordpress";
}
```